# How to extract string in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string in this format:

```
var a="input_[2][invoiceNO]";
```

I want to extract "invoiceNo" string. I've tried:

```
var a="input_[2][invoiceNO]";
    var patt = new RegExp('\[(.*?)\]');
    var res = patt.exec(a);
```

However, I get the following output:

```
Array [ "[2]", "2" ]
```

I want to extract only `invoiceNo` from the string.

**Note: Input start can be any string and in place of number `2` it can be any number.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check if the `[...]` before the necessary `[InvoiceNo]` contains digits and is preceded with `_` with this regex:

```
/_\[\d+\]\s*\[([^\]]+)\]/g
```

Explanation:

- `_` - Match underscore
- `\[\d+\]` - Match `[1234]`-like substring
- `\s*` - Optional spaces
- `\[([^\]]+)\]` - The `[some_invoice_123]`-like substring

You can even use this regex to find invoice numbers inside larger texts.

The value is in capture group 1 (see `m[1]` below).

Sample code:

```js
var re = /_\[\d+\]\s*\[([^\]]+)\]/g; 
var str = 'input_[2][invoiceNO]';
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    alert(m[1]);
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/\[(\w{2,})\]/
```

and grab captured group #1 from resulting array of `String.match` function.

```
var str = 'input_[2][invoiceNO]'
var m = str.match(/\[(\w{2,})\]/);
//=> ["[invoiceNO]", "invoiceNO"]
```

PS: You can also use negative lookahead to grab same string:

```
var m = str.match(/\[(\w+)\](?!\[)/);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a="input_[2][invoiceNO]";
var patt = new RegExp('\[(.*?)\]$');
var res = patt.exec(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a="input_[2][invoiceNO]";
var patt = new RegExp(/\]\[(.*)\]/);
var res = patt.exec(a)[1];
console.log(res);
```

Output:

```
invoiceNO
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like so: `\[([^[]+)\]$`. This will extract the content within the last set of brackets. Example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/bV6jU7/1).

Answer (score 0):

Use the greediness of `.*`

```
var a="input_[2][invoiceNO]";
var patt = new RegExp('.*\[(.*?)\]');
var res = patt.exec(a);
```